# Center TextArea upon node hover in LineChart JavaFX?

Tags: java, javafx, hover, textarea, linechart

I'm writing a program that tracks the user's mood based on daily input, saves each entry to a folder as a text file (including date and time of entry, as well as mood rating from 1-5) and generates a JavaFX linechart with Date of Entry as the x-axis and Mood as the y-axis, to show how user's mood fluctuates over time.

I just successfully added the ability to hover over any node on the LineChart to display the associated entry in a TextArea. The only problem that I can't seem to fix is: **How do I center said TextArea in the middle of the linechart?**

Because what's happening is the textarea is appearing at the same location as the linechart node that the user is hovering, and is causing major readability issues with the nodes that are close to the edge (as depicted here: [TextArea overlaps with linechart borders](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dCkwK.png))

Here is the code for creating the TextArea upon hover. If you need more information/code snippets, let me know and I'll happily provide it. Any help would be greatly appreciated!

```
class HoveredThresholdNode extends StackPane {
    HoveredThresholdNode(String date, int mood, int index) {
      setPrefSize(13, 13);

      TextArea entry = createDataThresholdLabel(date, mood, index);

      setOnMouseEntered(new EventHandler<MouseEvent>() {
        @Override public void handle(MouseEvent mouseEvent) {

          /**
          *Right here is where I need to change the location of 
          *the TextArea on the linechart, but I don't know how
          */

          getChildren().setAll(entry);
          toFront();
        }
      });
      setOnMouseExited(new EventHandler<MouseEvent>() {
        @Override public void handle(MouseEvent mouseEvent) {
          getChildren().clear();
          setCursor(Cursor.DEFAULT);
        }
      });
    }

    private TextArea createDataThresholdLabel(String date, int mood, int index) {
        //Creates&returns TextArea, left out code as it's irrelevant
        //Don't worry about index parameter, it's just used for retrieving entry
    }
}
```

Comment: Have you tried putting the `LineChart` in a `StackPane` then adding a `TextField` wrapped in a `VBox` / `HBox` to do the centering for you? I use this technique for creating popups in my JavaFx applications. All the centering is handled by JavaFx rather in this case. (if you need an example I can try to whip one up)

Comment: Hmm, interesting! The Linechart is currently in a grid pane but i didn't wrap the textfield in any layouts. I'll try it now!

Comment: Did wrapping the text field work?

Comment: Yeah it did actually, thanks for the recommendation! My bad I forgot to comment on here again.

Comment: I submitted my comment as an answer so you can mark it correct for anyone else that might stumble upon this later :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try putting the LineChart in a StackPane then adding a TextField wrapped in a VBox / HBox to do the centering for you. I use this technique for creating popups in my JavaFx applications. All the centering is handled by JavaFx rather in this case. The structure would look like this:

- Stack Pane

  - Line Chart
  - VBox / HBox

    - TextField